# Upgrade a reference dll in a C# project without recompiling the project

Tags: c#, dll, reference, version, assembly-resolution

I need to take a built version of an C# application and change one of the reference dll's.  What is the best way to do this, I have specific version turned off on the reference dll but as soon as I test replacing the dll with a newer version, I get the "Could not load file or assembly XXXXX, Version=XXXXX.  Is there a way to stop the loader from caring about the version of the dll so the dll will just attempt to load?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you can do this - see the MSDN article [Redirecting Assembly Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28VS.71%29.aspx).

You should read the whole document, but it essentially involves either the assembly's publisher creating a 'publisher policy file' or the consumer adding a `bindingRedirect` to an `app.config` file, like this (copied directly from the article):

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="myAssembly"
                           publicKeyToken="32ab4ba45e0a69a1"
                           culture="en-us" />
         <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0"
                          newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

A few notes:

- If you haven't explicitly specified
  your culture (as many don't), it will
  be "neutral" rather than "en-us".
- If you don't already know it, you can
  get the assembly's public key token
  using the strong name utility, like
  this: `sn -t [AssemblyPath]`

Comment: That would require a recompile, wouldn't it?

Comment: Or, os the configuration file checked only at runtime?

Comment: Those xml files are checked at runtime.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf(VS.71).aspx

Comment: @Michael - indeed, what Brian said. :)

Comment: Can I use this `Publisher Policy File` to reference any version of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint` assembly from my C# WinForms app?

Comment: What if publicKeyTokens are different? I had publicKeyToken="null" in old assembly. And this solution does not help me.

Comment: Update link [Redirecting Assembly Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) and [How the Runtime Locates Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/how-the-runtime-locates-assemblies)