# Assembly version mis-match

Tags: .net, reference, .net-assembly

I am creating an application using NServiceBus version 2.0.0.1219 and I need to reference another assembly created by someone else (old assembly), but that assembly references NServiceBus version 2.0.0.1071 which leads to a failure to execute in my application.

How can i let the "old assembly" know I have version 2.0.0.1219 of NServiceBus, it can use this instead of version 2.0.0.1071?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'NServiceBus, Version=2.0.0.1071, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrade a reference dll in a C# project without recompiling the project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461565/upgrade-a-reference-dll-in-a-c-project-without-recompiling-the-project)

Comment: Modified tags: the [assembly] tag is for assembly-language questions.

Comment: @Jeff The solution is similar however the question is not the same.